Can I expect "time now" with leniency by a few minutes?
I'm using the dayjs function and wanted to try and add some leniency to the "time now" so that my test doesn't fail if it takes longer than a minute to run/load.
Currently I have the below ;
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const timeNow = dayjs().format("H:mm");
cy.get('#dateTime').contains(timeNow)

But wondering if I can add something into the timeNow const to allow a 2-3 minute leniency (i.e. timeNow recorded at 9:30, but want to accept any time between 9:27 and 9:33) as I'm getting a failure 50% of the time if the test doesn't get to that step within the minute.

timeNow is just a string, you can manipulate its value before assigning to const whatever you want. Just ask yourself how often you are going to alter this, when there will be 9:34, 9:41, etc.?

@RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure I understand, sorry. How do I do that so that it accepts 9:27 or 9:28 or 9:29 or 9:30 or 9:31 or 9:32 or 9:33 given timeNow is 9:30?

@kkibbey apologies for misunderstanding. I can see now you're trying to find the element in the DOM by the time value using Cypress. I thought you were trying to allow a skew value on the entered value.

To make time-related tests rock solid, use the cy.clock() command. This stops (or should stop) the app's clock from moving on.
So you can grab the value from dayJs and it will still be correct later in the test, no matter how long it takes to get to the second line (mostly).
The caveats are about when the value is set in the element - if there is some API call happening, then the app sets the time, so need to be smart about when you take the timeNow value.
Your question isn't very complete, but maybe the example in the docs will illustrate
cy.clock()
cy.visit('/index.html')
cy.tick(1000)
cy.get('#seconds-elapsed').should('have.text', '1 seconds')
cy.tick(1000)
cy.get('#seconds-elapsed').should('have.text', '2 seconds')

By the way, .contains() is probably the wrong fit for this problem. It's a selection query, but you want to vary the thing you are selecting with (i.e timeNow) so obviously that's not going to wotk.
Try using .should() instead and a within assertion
cy.get('#datetime')
  .invoke('parseInt')
  .should('be.within', timeNow, timeNow + 60000)

Obviously you want the timNow value to be numeric.

Sorry, what is the purpose of .invoke('parseInt')? I've not had much experience with invoke and this step is failing. The issue and reason that i used contain initially is that I'm searching in a string that reads like "16/07/2024, 12:30" and just want to check that it contains the time... I am currently seeding data at the start of the test and the issue is that by the time it reaches my step, a minute may have passed.

Also, I cannot use cy.clock() as it seems to break other features on the page

The clock command is the correct way to perform this test. What does "break other features on the page" mean?

There is another step earlier in the test that seems to have trouble loading data when I used cy.clock(), likely because it is an iframe. If I put it immediately before my timeNow steps, it is too late to freeze the time.

If you want to check 9:27 or 9:28 or 9:29 then use a oneOf assertion.
cy.get('#dateTime')
  .then($el => {
    return $el.text().split(' ')[1]  // "16/07/2024, 12:30" -> "12:30"
  })
  .should('be.oneOf', ['9:27' '9:28', '9:29']) 

but its definitely a bad strategy, because how can you be sure of the delta in the time? The clock command is by far the best option.

This won't work as the time will not always be 9:30 in case of my example.

@kibby you seem to be flip-flopping a bit here.
